# iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor with inside some integer value, i need to create a new tensor with all the value from the integer `value*49` to `value*49+49`.

Example: `tf.random.uniform()` generates values `[0,1]`
Then i need a new tensor with values: `[0,1,2,3,..48, 98, 99, ..., 147]
But if i do something like this:

```
indices = tf.constant([], tf.int32)
for index in tf.random.uniform((51,), minval=0, maxval=62, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32):
    tensor1 = tf.constant([x for x in range(index * 49, index * 49 + 49)])
    indices = tf.concat([indices, tensor1], 0)
temp = tf.gather(huge_tensor, indices, axis=0)
```

I get this error:
`OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over tf.Tensor is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.`

I need to do something like this because i will later use `tf.gather` to gather from another huge tensor, all the rows using the `indices` tensor. If there is a way to tell `tf.gather` to grab all the rows directly instead of creating the new tensor `indices` is even better.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I have a tensor with 51 integer values that are indices. For each indices corrispond 49 rows of another tensor (4000 rows), so basically i need to extract 51*49 rows from that tensor. For example, for index 0 corrispond row 0-48 of the tensor. I hope this explain what i need to achieve

Comment: It's `[3136,512]`

Comment: What shape should `ìndices` and `huge_tensor` have?

Comment: Oh sorry, let me clarify. `huge_tensor` is the one with shape `[3136,512]`. `Indices` is a tensor with shape `[51*49,]`  since it's 1d with inside all the indices. The tensor i will need to have at the end of the tf.gather function is a tensor with shape `[51*49, 512]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239128/discussion-between-fanto-and-alonetogether).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `tf.TensorArray` and `tf.range`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random.uniform((51,), minval=0, maxval=62, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32)
indices = tf.TensorArray(tf.int32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
huge_tensor = tf.random.normal((3136, 512))

for i in tf.range(tf.shape(x)[0]):
  indices = indices.write(indices.size(), tf.range(x[i] * 49, x[i] * 49 + 49))

tf.print(indices.stack().shape)
result = tf.gather(huge_tensor, indices.stack(), axis=0)
result_shape = tf.shape(result)
result = tf.reshape(result, (result_shape[0] * result_shape[1], result_shape[2]))
tf.print(result.shape)
```

```
TensorShape([51, 49])
TensorShape([2499, 512])
```

Using `tf.range`, I create 1D sequences based on each value in x. Then I apply `stack()` to the array `indices`, which returns the sequences as a stacked tensor.